# How to detect a 'pinch out' in a list of containers?

Tags: codenameone

I want to be able to pinch two containers in a list of containers away from each other to insert a new empty container between them. Similar to how the iPhone app “Clear” inserts new tasks (see for example the very first picture on this page https://www.raywenderlich.com/22174/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-33 - the small red container is inserted when the two sorounding containers are pinched away from each other). Any hints on how I can achieve this in Codename One?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would override the `pinch` method to implement pinch to zoom or similar calls. However, this won't work in this case as the pinch will exceed component boundaries and it wouldn't work.

The only way I can think of doing this is to override the `pointerDragged(int[],int[])` method in `Form` and detect the pinch motion as growing to implement this. You can check out the code for pinch in `Component.java` as it should be a good base for this:

```
public void pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y) {
    if (x.length > 1) {
        double currentDis = distance(x, y);

        // prevent division by 0
        if (pinchDistance <= 0) {
            pinchDistance = currentDis;
        }
        double scale = currentDis / pinchDistance;
        if (pinch((float)scale)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    pointerDragged(x[0], y[0]);
}
private double distance(int[] x, int[] y) {
    int disx = x[0] - x[1];
    int disy = y[0] - y[1];
    return Math.sqrt(disx * disx + disy * disy);
}
```

Adding the entry is simple, just place a blank component in the place and grow its preferred size until it reaches the desired size.

Comment: I can't seem to test pinching out with two fingers in the simulator (on a Mac) - I've seen that it should be possible to do using right-click and move away from upper-left corner (or with two-finger swipe on Mac) but I can't get it to work. How to do it correctly?

Comment: We don't support that. I use a Mac too and would love that but the Java API we rely on for building the simulator doesn't get that event. There are some "hacky" libraries but integrating them isn't ideal. I think the best way to do this is to finally launch instant run/on device debugging which would make it easy to run instantly on the device.