# How to prevent the end of drag (or pinch) from being passed to e.g. buttons below the fingers?

Tags: codenameone

I've implemented my own support for PinchOut (as proposed in an earlier [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673861/how-to-detect-a-pinch-out-in-a-list-of-containers/39677113?noredirect=1#comment83083987_39677113)) to insert elements into a list. To insert elements I also need to detect a pinch at the top of the list, where one finger is on the Titlebar. I've done this by overwriting the `Form.pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y)` which will do the insertion etc and which 'consumes' the call (by NOT calling `super.Form.pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y)`). However, when releasing the two fingers, it sometimes triggers an action below one of the fingers, e.g. a titlebar command, or a button in the list element. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `pointerReleased` as well. If a pinch operation happens you need to detect that, then within `pointerReleased` do:

```
 public pointerReleased(int[] x, int[] y) {
      if(pinch) return;
      super.pointerReleased(x, y);
 }

 public pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
      if(pinch) return;
      super.pointerReleased(x, y);
 }
```

Notice you need to do it for both methods as some OS's send the array version and some send the int version of the callback.